# Правильно распарсить xml

Tags: c#, xml, xmlparser

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь правильно распарсить xml такого вида:

```
<MMWEATHER>
<REPORT type="frc3">
 <TOWN index="33345" sname="%CA%E8%E5%E2" latitude="50" longitude="30">
  <FORECAST day="17" month="05" year="2013" hour="15" tod="2" predict="0" weekday="6">
   <PHENOMENA cloudiness="1" precipitation="10" rpower="0" spower="0"/>
   <PRESSURE max="746" min="744"/>
   <TEMPERATURE max="25" min="23"/>
   <WIND min="2" max="4" direction="2"/>
   <RELWET max="65" min="63"/>
   <HEAT min="22" max="24"/>
  </FORECAST>
 </TOWN>
</REPORT>
</MMWEATHER>
```

Вот, что написал:

```
List<string> WeatherList = new List<string>();
            foreach (XmlNode node in xmldoc.DocumentElement)
            {
                int i = 0;
                if (node.LocalName == "FORECAST")
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        WeatherList.Insert(i, child.Name + child.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
```

К сожалению, не работает =( Подскажите пожалуйста, где тут затаилась ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запишите XML в XmlDocument.

Затем:

```
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load("http://informer.gismeteo.ru/xml/33345_1.xml");
        foreach (XmlNode node1 in xml.SelectNodes("/MMWEATHER/REPORT/TOWN/FORECAST"))
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node2 in node1.ChildNodes)
            {
                string temp = node2.Attributes["precipitation"].Value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Написал по Вашему примеру и все же не выходит. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @katch, какие ошибки?

Comment: Никакой ошибки. Просто значения не возвращаются.

Comment: _http://informer.gismeteo.ru/xml/33345_1.xml вот этот xml пытаюсь парсить. (Только первый блок FORECAST )

Comment: @katch, необходимо правильно указать корневой элемент. я ж пример работы писал. правильный код - в апдейте ответа